# Text from URL in HTML element ".split is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vwo

I am creating a AB Test with VWO. For this test I want to take the name out of the url and insert it in a link element. What I have works functionally, but an error appears in the console. I don't understand why and how I can solve it.

```
vwo_$(document).ready(function() {
  vwo_$('BODY > SCRIPT:first-child + HEADER + MAIN > DIV#content:first-child > SECTION:first-child > DIV:first-child > DIV:first-child > DIV:first-child + DIV > ASIDE:first-child > DIV:first-child + DIV + A').replaceWith("<a id=\"ABtestelement\" href=\"/anastia/blog\">Homepage blog ↑</a>");
    var XXXXXURL      = window.location.href;
    var XXXXXURLsplit = XXXXXURL.toString().split("/");
    // Returns full URL
    document.getElementById("ABtestelement").text = 'Meer blogposts van '+ XXXXXURLsplit[3] +' ↑';
});
```

The error it gives:

```
Uncaught TypeError: XXXXXURL.split is not a function
```

Updated the code: I first add the ID to the element, I know it is not the correct way to to it, but the other function to target it did not work.

Comment: I don't think that code is causing that problem; if it were, the code wouldn't work.

Comment: Check the line number where the error comes. @Pointy is right. Code is correct error must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: have you console output ? check are you getting this index which is in array `XXXXXURLsplit[3]`

Comment: It says (program):6. Not sure what or where that is.

Comment: Why is the error message different than the code that is displayed above?

Comment: Your `.split()` call in the code is correct. The error message you provide cannot come from the code snippet above (because your code does not contain the statement `XXXXXURL.split`). This type of error typically suggests that somehow XXXXXURL is undefined (or at least not a string).

Comment: This is all the code I have and added. I thought the problem would be this:

    var XXXXXURLsplit = XXXXXURL.toString().split("/");

Any idea on how I could do it differently?

Comment: Do you need to clear your console log? Sometimes I'll forget the log grows a history and think the error has not gone away after I've corrected the bug. Program 6 should be the line in your JavaScript file where this error originally occurred.

Comment: The `.toString()` is not necessary. If (after clearing log) you add `console.log(XXXXXURL);`, what output do you get?

Comment: @wintvelt: 

console.log(XXXXXURL); gives:
VM16247:2 split() { [native code] }
undefined.

It seems that the problem occurs after the VWO variation is loaded.

Comment: Again an error message with `split()` in it. Which cannot come from the `console.log()`. Looks like the error message originates from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and you were all right! Apparently, I also added half the code to the global Javascript of all variations causing the error. Thanks for your help.